# Find all dependencies contributed by BOM in gradle 5

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, maven-bom

Is there a way to list the dependencies of a bom from gradle script

Suppose I have the following gradle file

```
dependencies {
    //*** bill of materials
    springBom platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.2.RELEASE")
  }
```

and I want to list all the dependencies contributed by this BOM to gradle, is there a way to list them using `gradlew`/`gradle` command?

Answer (score 2):

The BOM support of Gradle will transform all `dependencyManagement` entries in Gradle [dependency constraints](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_dependency_constraint).

Constraints do not participate in dependency resolution *unless* there is a dependency (direct or transitive) that targets the same module.
As such, running something like `./gradlew dependencies --configuration springBom` will only list the BOM itself and no constraints (assuming that configuration does not have another dependency added to it).

However, when leveraging the BOM data, you could run `./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` and you would see all *active* constraints as child nodes under the BOM dependency.

Comment: Reason why I want to know what I wanted to know is, I would like to check if a given dependency is contributed by any of the existing BOMs that are currently associated. If none have the required dependency, I would want to go ahead and add dependency's version variant. E.g, `spring-boot-dependencies` contributes quite a lot. I want to know if I can expect a dependency to be provided (or) not. Appreciate if there is a way to find this info without fiddling with physical files/going to mvnrepository

Comment: Right now the easiest is to add the dependency to the project, without a version. Then run `./gradlew dependencies`. If the dependency status is `FAILED` then no version was provided and you should add it. Otherwise a version was provided and you are good to go.